# How to enable MSDTC on SQL Server 2014?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014

I have installed SQL Server Enterprise version on my local Windows server, and now I have need help to enable MSDTC services.

I have contacted Microsoft help, but they are taking a long time to respond.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this for windows Server 2008 r2

1. Click **Start**, click **Run**, type **dcomcnfg** and then click **OK** to open **Component Services**.
2. In the console tree, click to expand **Component Services**, click to expand **Computers**, click to expand **My Computer**, click to expand **Distributed Transaction Coordinator** and then click **Local DTC**.
3. Right click **Local DTC** and click **Properties** to display the **Local DTC Properties** dialog box.
4. Click the **Security** tab.
5. Check mark **"Network DTC Access"** checkbox.
6. Finally check mark **"Allow Inbound"** and **"Allow Outbound"** checkboxes.
7. Click **Apply**, **OK**.
8. A message will pop up about **restarting** the service.
9. Click **OK** and That's all.

Answer (score 0):

To add-on, below is how to check the DTC service.

1. Launch **Run** in windows run dialog then entered **dcomcnfg** and press **OK**
2. Expanded **Component Services**" > **Computers** > **My Computer** > **Distributed Transaction Coordinator** > **Local DTC** > **Transaction Statistics**
3. Execute a distributed transaction query in **SSMS** to monitor DTC